# How to install kde-plasma with lightdm instead of kdm

Tags: system-installation, kde, lightdm, login-screen

I like `lightdm` and especially its `webkit-greeter` a lot. Is there a way to install `kde` without installing `kdm` and using `lightdm` instead?

I have tried everything from installing `kdm` and then remove it to `dpkg-reconfigure kdm` and `lightdm` to `lightdm` is the default. but I always got `kdm` when I boot up or a broken system, when I remove it completely.

Does anyone know how to get `kde` together with `lightdm`?

By the way. I am doing this on a minimal installation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your initial setup is a minimal installation, I'll take [Ubuntu 14.04.1 Server](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso) as the base OS.

After installation, all that you get is a command-line prompt without `lightdm` nor a desktop environment.

Open a user session and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightdm-webkit-greeter --no-install-recommends
sudo apt-get install lightdm --no-install-recommends
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends
sudo reboot
```

Now the lightdm greeter will open a kde plasma desktop:

[image]

Comment: T'es incroyable, toi...  ;-)  As from now with bounties where you're participating, I'm not even trying!  >:)

Comment: @Fabby Merci, but continue to propose great answers! I think we're all looking for questions where the problem solving part 1. is fun and 2. can teach us new stuff about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default greeter by changing the configuration file under the `[SeatDefaults]` section, to state:

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

[SeatDefaults]
...
greeter-session=lightdm-yourgreeter-greeter
```

Enabling `lightdm`

Make sure to enable `lightdm.service` [using systemctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Using_units) so `lightDM` will be started at boot.

Command line tool

`Lightdm` offers a command line tool, `dm-tool` which can be used to lock the current seat, switch sessions, etc, which is useful with  window managers and for testing. To see a list of available commands, execute:

```
dm-tool --help
```

Comment: Have you seen the last sentence of this post? Thank you but there is no desktop installed., yet